# Parse SDK for iOS; Using UISearchBar on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm retrieving data from parse and put it the tableview but when I'm trying to also add a searchbar I don't know how can I manage it. What should I do on tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method instead of  NSLog(@"do something!!");

My code is below and thanks for any help.

retrieve from parse code is below

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *retrieveName = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"pFihrist"];

    [retrieveName findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

UITableView Delegate code is below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [nameArray count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"fCell";
    FihristCell *cell = (FihristCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FihristCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        PFObject *tempObject = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.cellProfName.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"pName"];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"do something!!");

    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell tapped");
}
```

search methods code is below

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [nameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What difficulty you found in this??

Comment: I don't know how I'll get filtered records and show them on tableview.

Comment: There is very good tutorial regarding Search in IOS. Go through [this link] (http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/). tell me if you need more help

Comment: Yes, I checked that tutorial and it is really good one. But couldnt handle when I want to use that tutorial with pars sdk.

Comment: I don't think it has any work with your SDK. Its just filter data which you have given to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Register the Cell to display you searched items

You have to register the cell to searchdisplaycontroller as well.

[Important: You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:)

in View did load

If you are Creating cell in code

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] 
    forCellReuseIdentifier:@"IdentifierForCell"];
```

If you are Creating cell in nib

```
  [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellNibName" bundle:nil]
                                        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"IdentifierForCell"];


2. Deque corresponding cell to search display controller table with identifier

    FihristCell *cell = (FihristCell *)[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

3. configure that cell to display instead of NSLog
```